# Access issue with flask and heroku

Tags: heroku, flask, terminal

I am trying to push a small practice app called "flask" from git to heroku, yet, no matter what I do, I encounter the same issue when I use any of these commands in the terminal:

```
heroku logs --app flask
heroku access --app flask
heroku git:remote -a flask
```

results always in the same output:

```
You do not have access to the app flask.
```

The code of the app.py file:

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') 
def hello_world():
    return 'What a beautiful, rainy day!'

@app.route('/templates') 
def index():
    return render_template('hello.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

I hope that is sufficient information for you guys anyways let me know! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

fixed the issues with:

```
heroku create
heroku git:remote [appname]
```

can't access something which is not existing...